# Jquery, поиск по колонки таблицы

Tags: jquery

У меня есть таблица с тремя колонками.

```
+------------+------------+------------+
| user_login |    date    |   product  |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 31.03.2999 |     hat    |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 31.03.1999 | sunglasses |
+------------+------------+------------+
|    neo     | 01.04.2999 | sunglasses |
+------------+------------+------------+
|  trinity   | 01.04.1999 |     hat    |
+------------+------------+------------+
```

так же у меня есть функция которая ищет текст по всем колонкам

```
$("#myFilter").on("keyup", function () {
    var inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTebleId tr").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1)
    });
});
```

Подскажите как переписать готовую функцию для поиска значений не в строке, а в третий колонке 'product' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дайте колонке `product` класс к примеру `class="product"` каждой ячейке. И тогда получится так:

```
$("#myFilter").on("keyup", function () {
    var inputValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myTebleId tr").filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).children('.product').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) > -1)
    });
});
```

```js
$(".myFilter").on("keyup", function() {
  var productValue = $('.input-product').val().toLowerCase();
  var userLoginValue = $('.input-user_login').val().toLowerCase();

  $("#myTebleId tr").each(function() {
    $(this).toggle(          ($(this).children('.user_login').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(userLoginValue) > -1) &&         ($(this).children('.product').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(productValue) > -1));
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input class="myFilter input-user_login">
<input class="myFilter input-product">


<table id="myTebleId">
  <tr>
    <td class="user_login">Первый</td>
    <td class="product">Продукт</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="user_login">Первый</td>
    <td class="product">another</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="user_login">Второй</td>
    <td class="product">еще продукт</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="user_login">Anothe one</td>
    <td class="product">product</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо!

Comment: Подскажите как я могу навесить ещё один фильтр на "user_login", что бы фильтры работали друг в друге

Comment: Так дайте ему тот же класс. Не обязательно писать `product` можно использовать универсальный и понятный класс к примеру `isfiltered` давайте его всем нужным колонкам и в children фильтруйте только эти классы

Comment: тогда это будет один фильтр на несколько колонок, мне хотелось бы сделать что вроде этого: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Filter-Html-Table-with-Multiple-Criteria-multifilter/

Comment: Так вы не говорили что у вас несколько фильтров на разные колонки :)  Или два фильтра на разные колонки или передавайте через дата свойства классы колонок. Допустим в первом input добавьте `data-class="user_login"` тогда в самой функции получите название ребенка через data атрибуты и ищите по ним. Только функцию тоже перепишете не под id="myFilter" а под класс.

Comment: Я новичок в этом деле, не могли бы Вы написать пример кода?)
Заранее спасибо!)

Comment: Кинул рабочий пример

Comment: Спасибо, но это немного не то))) они перебивают друг друга, хотелось бы накладывать эффект от всех фильтров)

Comment: Вы не постоянны ) Добавил, думаю далее по аналогу реализуете

Comment: Огромное спасибо!)))